# How to reduce boilerplate code in JAX-RS Rest Service?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, boilerplate

I am creating a REST API with JAX-RS and Jersey.

I offer multiple "types", such as event and user information.
The problem is, I am getting a lot of redundant code, and I don't know how to help myself.

Per "type"  I have a model, a DAO and a Resource.
I presume one could save alot of typing in the Resources.

Here an example:

```
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource  {

@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;
@Context
private Request request;
@Context
private String id;
@Context 
private HttpServletResponse response;


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Object> getUsers() {
    return UserDao.instance.listElements();
}


@GET
@Path("count")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public int getCount() {
    return UserDao.instance.listElements().size();
}


@GET
@Path("{id}")
public User getUser(@PathParam("id") String id,
        @Context HttpHeaders headers,
        @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException{
    AuthChecker.check(headers, servletResponse);
    Object obj=UserDao.instance.getElement(id);
    if(obj==null){
        response.sendError(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode());
    }
    return (User)obj;
}
```

. . . and so on.

So for the type "event" all those functions are basically the same. What can i do to save typing all this stuff for multiple "types".

Comment: I guess the authentication should be done for every request, not just for the GET by id?? You'd better use an [Authentication Filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e12030) (and quite a few SO questions). You could also use [Exception Mappers](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d0e6524). For the rest, not much to do depending on the services you need to publish.